# CIFS share: files getting locked with VIM but not with Nano

Tags: vim, permissions, cifs, nano, locked-files

I have an heterogeneous share, between Linux and Windows systems, hosted on a NetApp. On Linux, I mount the share with those options:

```
mount.cifs -o username=`logname`,dom=DOMAIN,cifsacl,multiuser,user_xattr,sec=krb5,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,mapchars //host/share /home/`logname`/mnt
```

All permissions (set from Windows) are correctly honored. However, there is a strange behavior:

If a user opens a file he created on Windows (or a copy of it) with `vim` or `vi`, the file is opened in `readonly` mode. If he modifies and writes it with `:w!`, **the file gets locked**, and cannot be read anymore, even by an administrator or root (`permission denied`). **It can only be deleted** by one of those. Gedit opens such files the same way: read only.

However, when such a file is opened with `nano`, it is precised `[converted from DOS format]`, and when saved, it is flagged `[dos format]`. The file gets written, and no problem occurs at all.

Do you have any idea why it behaves like that ?

EDIT: I already tried to disable backups and swap files in `/etc/vimrc` with those options :

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
```

Also tried `:w! ++ff=dos` and `:w! ++ff=unix`, without success.

Comment: I suspect that this is a side effect of how Vim handles "overwriting" a file. It actually moves a file aside and writes a new one, while attempting to preserve the file's OS permissions. Try turning off the 'writebackup' option and and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I have already done that, I edited the initial post to precise it. At the end of my "/etc/vimrc", I have those options : set nobackup, set nowritebackup, set noswapfile. Same behavior...

Comment: Did you check the actual file permissions before and after?

Comment: The share being NTFS-style permissions from a NetApp, and access being granted with a TGS, all Windows-made files appear to be root:root 000 . But permissions set in Windows are still honored, it is just not visible. So yes, i am sure about permissions, but it is not displayed in Linux, only honored. I mean, there is no problem with nano, only with vi and vim. EDIT: i'm going to check from Windows before and after, then i post again

Comment: Ok, indeed, permissions get overwritten. Explanation: FileA is writable by "Domain Admins" and "GroupA". FileA is copied and named FileB. FileB has the same ACLs. I CANNOT (i just discovered that) overwrite FileB with nano, and I can overwrite it with vi/vim with :w!. If doing so, it changes ACL to the user who edited it, + groups "All users" and "Domain Users". They all have only attributes ticked: "read attributes", "reading of read attributes" and "read authorization". Those last 3 do not honor, either with Windows or Linux : file is untouchable, except for being removed by an admin.

Comment: To summarize : nobody can copy a file from Linux, or the ACL get destroyed and the file is lost.